# mysql Can I sort on earliest of two dates?

Tags: mysql

the table looks like this:

```
id    date1        date2
1     05-09-2018   01-09-2018
2     03-09-2018   06-09-2018
3     02-09-2018   07-09-2018
```

In my query i want to sort on the earliest of the 2 dates so it looks like this:

```
id    date1        date2
1     05-09-2018   01-09-2018
3     02-09-2018   07-09-2018 
2     03-09-2018   06-09-2018
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `least()`

```
select * from your_table
order by least(date1, date2)
```

but that can't make use of indexes. A faster query should be

```
select * from your_table
order by case when date1 < date2 
              then date1 
              else date2
         end
```