# Sorting on the earliest of 3 dates with null values

Tags: mysql

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52166026/mysql-can-i-sort-on-earliest-of-two-dates/52166050#52166050) question i developed a piece of code looking like this:

```
order by 
case 
    when bez_datum IS NULL
    then
        case
        when verg_datum IS NULL
        then event_datum
        when event_datum IS NULL
        then verg_datum
        when verg_datum < event_datum
        then verg_datum
        else event_datum
        end
    when verg_datum IS NULL
    then 
        case
        when event_datum IS NULL
        then bez_datum
        else if(bez_datum < event_datum, bez_datum, event_datum)
        end
    when event_datum IS NULL
    then if(bez_datum < verg_datum, bez_datum, verg_datum)
    else if(bez_datum < verg_datum, if(bez_datum < event_datum, bez_datum, event_datum), if(verg_datum < event_datum, verg_datum, event_datum))
end
```

The problem is that my sorting still doesn't go as planned. when i execute this code i get this result:
[image: order by executed]

to be clear when i have a table looking like this:

```
id    date1        date2
1     05-09-2018   01-09-2018
2     03-09-2018   06-09-2018
3     02-09-2018   07-09-2018 
4     05-09-2018   null
```

i want it to come out like this:

```
id    date1        date2        sorted on
1     05-09-2018   01-09-2018   01-09-2018
3     02-09-2018   07-09-2018   02-09-2018
2     03-09-2018   06-09-2018   03-09-2018
4     05-09-2018   null         05-09-2018
```

so the table should be sorted on the earliest of 2 dates not calculating null.(sorted on is not a column that should show up, it's just to show what is used to sort)

currently I have the impression that it only sorts on event_datum.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem, but you can use `coalesce` to pick the first non-null value of a list of values, so you could `order by coalesce(bez_datum, verg_datum, event_datum)` to use either date for the sorting. It sounds to me like you actually want `order by coalesce(bez_datum, verg_datum, event_datum), coalesce(verg_datum, event_datum), event_datum`, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @GolezTrol can you explain what this does? because from what i looked up  coalesce only returns the first non-null-value. but when the second non-null-value is lower i want this to take priority. how does this code implement this?

Comment: @GolezTrol Take by example the row with id 1, i want this row to be sorted by 01-09-2018 because this is the lowest date, and not by 05-09-2018 which is the first non null value

Comment: You can't use `=` for equality with NULL values. Use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use [`least`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least), which supports multiple values. Unfortunately `least` always returns `null` if one of the values is `null`. You could work around that using `coalesce`.

Your order by clause could look like this:

```
order by
  least(
    --       each date goes here...
    --           |
    --          \|/ 
    coalesce(bez_datum, verg_datum, event_datum),
    coalesce(verg_datum, bez_datum, event_datum),
    coalesce(event_datum, bez_datum, verg_datum)
  )
```

The important part here is that each of the dates is the first in one of the coalesces. The other two are just passed in any order to coalesce to make sure that each coalesce returns a relevant non-null value, (or null if all three dates would be null).